# Roll up summary functionality using trigger

Tags: trigger

//Getting an error while deleting the record on contact.. dereference to the null object

```
trigger ContactCountOnAccount on Contact (after insert, after update, after delete) {
    Set<Id> AccountIds = new Set<Id>();
    List<Account> AccountsToUpdate = new List<Account>();
    for(Contact c : trigger.new){
        AccountIds.add(c.AccountId);
    }
    if(trigger.isUpdate || trigger.isdelete){
        for(Contact o : trigger.old){
            AccountIds.add(o.AccountId);
        }
    }
    map<Id, Account> MapAcc = new map<Id, account>([SELECT id, No_of_Contacts__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN : AccountIds]);
    List<Account> LstAcc = New List<Account>([SELECT Id, No_of_Contacts__c, (SELECT Id FROM Contacts) FROM Account WHERE Id IN :AccountIds]);
    for(Account acc : LstAcc){
        MapAcc.get(acc.id).No_of_Contacts__c = acc.contacts.size();
        AccountsToUpdate.add(MapAcc.get(acc.id));
    }
    update AccountsToUpdate;
}
```

Comment: which line number ?

Comment: at line 4 i've added trigger.isinsert  , now its working fine

Comment: It is working fine up to 10,000 records, but what should i do achieve this scenario for more than 10,000.. If any solution would be appreciable.....thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to break the following code block :

```
    for(Account acc : LstAcc){
        MapAcc.get(acc.id).No_of_Contacts__c = acc.contacts.size();
        AccountsToUpdate.add(MapAcc.get(acc.id));
    }
```

to

```
            for(Account acc : LstAcc)
            {
                if(MapAcc.get(acc.id)!=null) 
                {
                    mapAcc.get(acc.id).No_of_Contacts__c = acc.contacts != null ? acc.contacts.size() : 0;
                    accountsToUpdate.add(MapAcc.get(acc.id));
                }
            }
```

Always check for `null` when using `Map` and `List`

Comment: Thanks for responding...i was facing an error that is, i'm to able to delete the record... but i have added trigger.isinsert context variable  to my snippet above the trigger.new context variable.. Now everything goes fie......